# Solve $3x^2+6x+5=0$ mod $89$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do you determine whether $3x^2+6x+5=0$ mod $89$ has a solution? WolframAlpha says no such solution exists. I am really curious as to how the fate of the statement was concluded.

Comment: As $(3,89)=1,$$$3x^2+6x+5\equiv0\pmod{89}\iff 9x^2+18x+15\equiv0\iff (3x+3)^2\equiv-6\equiv83$$ Now apply http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticReciprocityTheorem.html

Answer (score 2):

Apply the quadratic formula:

$$\Delta=6^2-4\cdot 3\cdot 5=-24=65\pmod{89}$$

$$\left(\frac{65}{89}\right)=\left(\frac{13}{89}\right)\left(\frac{5}{89}\right)\stackrel{\text{Quad. Recip.}}=\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{11}\right)\cdot 1=-1$$

This means that the expression

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2\cdot3}$$

cannot be solved $\;\pmod {89}\;$, which means the quadratic has no roots $\;\pmod{89}\;$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $3x^2+6x+5 = 3(x+1)^2 + 2$. Hence,
$$3x^2+6x+5 \equiv 0 \pmod{89} \implies 3(x+1)^2 \equiv -2 \pmod{89} \equiv 87 \pmod{89}$$
This gives us
$$(x+1)^2 \equiv 29 \pmod{87} \implies (x+1)^2 = 29(3k+1) \implies 29 \vert (x+1)^2 \implies 29^2 \vert (x+1)^2$$
Setting $x+1 = 29M$, we get that $$29M^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \implies M^2 \equiv 2 \pmod3$$
But any square is either $0\pmod3$ or $1 \pmod3$. Hence, no solution.